# Pass Complex and nested object as parameter to dotnet web service

Tags: android, web-services

I am trying to Pass Complex and nested object as parameter to `.net web service`.
The Complex object includes the another class object. Please help me

Comment: irrespective of whether your web service is a dotnet web service or anything else, you would pass the data in exactly the same way using one of the following:
1) URLConnection
2) HttpGet
3) HttpPost